# Update query error

Tags: sql-server

I am writing the following query to update price in a table(PartsPricing):

```
Update PartsPricing
set ppPrice = CEILING((select PP.ppPrice from 
                #tmp_PartstoUpdate TPU join PartsPricing PP 
                on TPU.ppPartNumber = PP.ppPartNumber 
                where PP.ppConditionID = 9  and PP.ppDeleted = 0)*.5)
where ppID in (select ppID from #tmp_PartstoUpdate)
```

When I run the query I get the following error:

```
Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.
```

I have tried every possible solution I could find online and none of them seemed to work. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead, this should basically do the same:

```
Update PP
set ppPrice = CEILING(PP.ppPrice * 0.5)
FROM PartsPricing PP 
INNER JOIN #tmp_PartstoUpdate TPU 
        ON TPU.ppPartNumber = PP.ppPartNumber 
where PP.ppConditionID = 9 and PP.ppDeleted = 0
```

Your problem is, that your subquery returns more than one row, which causes SQL Server to abort. He can't multiply multiple rows with one value and assign it to another (unless you're using an aggregation).

Comment: If this is the solution for your problem, you can mark it as your answer for everyone else looking for the same issue. :-)

Comment: I modified the above query to update Used Condition based on used price like this:

Comment: Ignore the preceding comment. I forgot to ask what aggregation do you suggest I use if I wanted to keep both subqueries in the first query I posted?

Comment: Maybe I don't get your question. What do you mean with "keep both subqueries"? You normally can't and shouldn't use two values to update one row, as always the last value will be updated. Or do you mean that you want to group them and Update them with an aggregation like `MAX()`?

Comment: Okay. Let me try again. The subquery filters price based on Factory New condition and multiply it by .5. This is a prerequisite condition in my update query. 
Your suggested query ran without any error and that is exactly what I wanted. That is why also I jumped into a quick conclusion that it worked. 
But when you restructured the update query like you did, it removed the prerequisite condition. Do you understand me now?

Comment: Well I've took a look at it. It is basically the same. Each condition is still the same. It only updates those parts, which are mentioned in `#tmp_PartstoUpdate` and it only updates those parts with the `ppConditionId = 9` and `ppDeleted = 0`. Which prerequisite condition is changed or left out?

Comment: #tmp_PartstoUpdate is a temporary table that contains parts with Used Condition price. The table we are trying to update is PartsPricing. 
The main purpose of the update query is to update Used Condition price based on Factory New price. 
Now, the select statement in the subquery filters Factory New price(The prerequisite condition) and then multiply it by .5. Do you see where I am going with this?

Comment: Yes but this still happens. You won't sum all factory new prices and update one part with the sum of all. Can you provide a create table statement of your temporary table? Can you provide an input and an output example for this?

Comment: This is the create statement for #tmp_PartstoUpdate table:  
    Select ppID, ppPartNumber, ppPrice, ppConditionID 
    into #tmp_PartstoUpdate
    From PartsPricing
    where ppConditionID = 1 and ppPrice = 0 And ppDeleted = 0
    and ppPartNumber in
     (Select PP.ppPartNumber from 
     PartsPricing PP join PartsMaster PM
     On PP.ppPartNumber = PM.pmPartNumber
     where ppConditionID = 9 and ppPrice > 0
     And PM.pmSystemTypeID = 2
     And PP.ppDeleted = 0
     And PM.pmDeleted = 0
     And PM.pmActive = 1)

Comment: This is the output example with two rows:
ppID ppPartNumber  ppPrice ppConditionID
242 6ES7193-4CA20-0AA0 0.00 1
258 6ES7193-4CA30-0AA0 0.00 1